# rsync: failed to connect to hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu (128.114.119.163)

Tags: server, connection, rsync

For reasons I don't understand, rsync does not work for me since today.
I tried to fix the problem by following steps described here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/628102/15-04-rsync-connection-refused
but it did not work...

I am working on a laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 as OS, and have a wired ethernet connection.
I made several queries on the UCSC server yesterday, so maybe their server blocks my connection ?

Example of a query I would like to do :

```
rsync -a -P rsync://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/database/cytoBand.txt.gz ./
```

Here is the Error message :

```
rsync: failed to connect to hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu (128.114.119.163): Connection refused (111)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(128) [Receiver=3.1.1]
```

Tell me what you think and if there is any solution to make it work again.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Edit:

UCSC answered me : no problem on their side. The problem definitely come from me. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a mail answer from a guy working at UCSC:

I tried the same command line but on the mirror site : ftp://hgdownload**-sd**.cse.ucsc.edu.

which gave this command line :

```
rsync -a -P rsync://hgdownload-sd.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/database/cytoBand.txt.gz ./
```

I tried it. It worked. 
And here comes the best part: in my case I try the command line that did not work... and it works again:

```
rsync -a -P rsync://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/database/cytoBand.txt.gz ./
```

So I did not had any explanations on where does the problem came from. But problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `rsync` daemon is not running on the remote host, or perhaps it is running on a non-standard port (default is 873).

It's also possible that connections are being blocked by a firewall. Were your earlier successful connections made from the same location, or are you now testing from elsewhere?

As a workaround you can access the files via HTTP using any browser or HTTP command line tools such as `curl`, `wget` et. al. Either of these should work:

```
$ curl http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/database/cytoBand.txt.gz -o cytoBand.txt.gz
$ wget http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/database/cytoBand.txt.gz
```

Comment: Hi.
I used it the last 2 days and it worked perfectly. 
Can you give me the command line you enter to check if rsync is running on the remote host ?

Comment: I can't tell with certainty whether the remote rsync server is running, but the error `Connection refused (111)` means that the remote host is rejecting connections. That could be because rsync is not running and so the port is not open, it's listening on a different port, or there is some other issue such as a firewall blocking the requests. Test with netcat: `nc -vv hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu 873`. This makes a TCP connection to the server and port on which the remote rsync daemon should be listening, if it is in fact there.

Comment: If it worked in the last 2 days, and UCSC have not changed anything at their end, then something has probably changed at your side. Were you perhaps inside the UCSC network when it was last successful? If so that could be explained as a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since rsync is still not working (I tweet to UCSC to ask about it),
I decided to use the tools curl  and wget that mhawke advised me, but using the ftp adresses instead of http (slower) :

```
curl ftp://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/database/cytoBand.txt.gz -o cytoBand.txt.gz

wget http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/database/cytoBand.txt.gz
```

If anyone has a solution for the rsync problem, or any informations saying that the problem could come from the UCSC server, I would be thankful. 
Cheers !

Edit:

I received an answer from UCSC : no problem about rsync on the side of the UCSC server. So the problem definitely comes from me. I tried on 3 different computers on different places, all running under Ubuntu 16.04. I am still looking for a solution.